# Weird output on edit text with alert Dialog

Tags: kotlin, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

[Weird output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoirL.png)

I'm getting this output on my alert dialog when I enter text.

Can someone maybe explain why this is happening.

No errors in logcat.

Here is my code for the Alert Dialog

```
private fun declineDialogBox() {
    val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)

    val inflater = layoutInflater
    val dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog, null)
    val toBeCorrected = dialogLayout.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText)

    dialogBuilder.setMessage("Reason is?")

            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Proceed") { dialog, id ->
                finish()
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Reason is $toBeCorrected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show()
            }
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog, id ->
            }
    val alert = dialogBuilder.create()
    alert.setView(dialogLayout)
    alert.setTitle("To Be Corrected")
    alert.show()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing the instance of `EditText` instead the `value`, add `.text` to get the value from `EditText`

```
 Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Reason is ${toBeCorrected.text}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```